# Google Play Internal test track testers can't download (this item isn't avalible)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mobile, google-play

Two users have the same error (This item isn't avalible)
I able to download and update the internal test

Both users have signed upto the program and
I have only made an internal test track

Both their emails are on the list

I ran out of ideas so I've also started closed beta testing but that'll be a few days

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFgaZ.jpg)

Check email list - both email on the list

Enabled developer mode on phones

Google play settings enabled internal app sharing

Both phone are shown as compatible and have a correct version of android